# Braking radiation (bremsstrahlung) and energy conservation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation

I'm aware there is a similar question about this: [Bremsstrahlung vs energy conservation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61458/bremsstrahlung-vs-energy-conservation)

However, I don't think the answer given actually answers the question, so I'll ask again:

Let's consider a high velocity electron passing close to a nucleus. As it moves away from the nucleus, it loses kinetic energy whilst increasing its electrical potential energy by the same amount.

There must be something missing in my understanding about the formation of bremsstrahlung. If all the electron's loss of kinetic energy is converted to electrical potential energy as it leaves the nucleus, where does the energy come from to create a radiated photon?

Comment: There is additional energy lost due to bremsstrahlung. That is, the electron looses more kinetic energy than it gains potential energy.

Comment: Surely the fact that it's a force comparable to the gravitational force, the loss in kinetic energy is exactly equal to the gain in electrical potential energy?

Comment: This is also not true for gravitation, there is a gravitational analogon "bremstrahlung". (Don't forget, massive binary objects in close orbits lose energy due to gravitational radiation). The point is that total energy is conserved (kinetic and potential of the particle plus radiated energy). Electrostatics and gravitostatics are nothing but $c \to \infty$ approximations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: the electron loses a bit more kinetic energy than you would expect by naive energy conservation. That extra energy is accounted for by the emitted light. Classically the reason the electron loses more energy is because it experiences a backward [radiation reaction force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force) on it when it emits the light.

Better answer: there's really no such thing as "potential energy". Energy is always the energy of *something*, like the kinetic energy of a particle or the energy density of a field. Potential energy as used in introductory physics is a placeholder for some kind of energy we don't want to keep track of explicitly. For example, the potential energy of two static charges
$$U(r) = \frac{q_1 q_2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r}$$
is really the energy of the static electric field they create, up to a constant.

In this situation, there is electromagnetic field energy and electron kinetic energy. Some of the latter is transferred to the former. There is no reason to expect that *all* of this energy will be in the form of static field energy, since the electron is accelerating; some appears as radiation. There's nothing particularly weird or paradoxical about this.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that there is no such thing as potential energy.

Comment: @my2cts Can you give an example?

Comment: Potential energy is the part of the energy of an object the depends on its position, to be distinguished from kinetic energy, which depends on its velocity.

The concept is used in every part of physics, so examples are everywhere.

Comment: @my2cts The "potential energy" of a charge in a field is fundamentally just field energy. If you count _both_ potential energy and field energy in your calculation, you will account for the same energy twice. Similarly the potential energy of a particle on a spring is really the energy of the atoms of the spring, and so on. Do you have a better example?

Comment: You have to come with sound arguments. Your reasoning in these posts is casual. Btw Feynman discussed field energy in his lectures. Do you agree with him or, if not, can you show that he is wrong?

Comment: knzhou, isn't the electrostatic force between a nucleus and an electron comparable to a gravitational field in that just like change in gpe= change in ke, change in epe=change in ke?

Comment: @KevinJu Yes, but GPE is merely a placeholder, it’s really gravitational field energy.

Comment: So are you saying that an analysis considering the electrostatic force and the work done by this force isn't the full picture?

Comment: @KevinJu. Yes, that’s right.

Comment: Your description in the end is OK, but the part about potential energy is misleading. Coulomb potential energy *is* energy of something: the something is the system of particles, just not the field. One can still define and use Coulomb potential energy even if the particles accelerate and the field energy differs.

Comment: @JánLalinský But this can be seriously misleading. Then it is natural for a beginner to think, "okay, then sum of the kinetic energy, the Coulomb potential energy, and the electromagnetic field energy is conserved". But this gives the wrong result because the same energy is double-counted.

Comment: @JánLalinský You could avoid it by manually splitting the field energy into "radiation energy" and "static field energy" (the latter of which is identified with the "Coulomb potential energy") but I don't think this is useful in general.

Comment: @knzhou, the concept of Coulomb potential energy indeed may be misleading if used wrong, for example if mixed up with the concept of field energy. You are right that the concept of field energy is the one to focus on here - but not because potential energy does not exist, but because field energy allows us to formulate local conservation of energy. -- The splitting you mention is a common procedure in theory of radiation of atoms and molecules.

Answer (score 1):

> If all the electron's loss of kinetic energy is converted to electrical potential energy as it leaves the nucleus,

Even in ideal Coulomb theory, not all kinetic energy is converted to potential energy; the nucleus is pulled by the electron and receives some kinetic energy as well. Then, both electron and nucleus move with non-zero acceleration.

In fully relativistic electromagnetic theory with only retarded interactions, two charged particles that move with acceleration will act on each other with EM forces that are not purely Coulombic. These forces are non-conservative; this means some energy will apparently get lost, so sum of kinetic energies after the encounter will be less than before. Of course, this lost energy is not actually lost, but will leak out from the system as EM energy flux, due to EM radiation such system produces.

Comment: Can you explain "two charged particles that move with acceleration will act on each other with EM forces that are not purely Coulombic."?

Comment: Accelerated charged particles produce magnetic field, and electric field different than the Coulomb field - the field is compressed in direction of motion, and there is also the induced field component, proportional to acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Potential energy is the part of the energy of an object the depends on its position, to be distinguished from kinetic energy, which depends on its velocity.

The concept is used in every part of physics, so examples are everywhere.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/216451)

Comment: The op is not asking a question. Instead he is making a statement.

Answer (score 0):

This belongs to  the quantum mechanical regime because, bremsstrahlung  appears on individual electrons, and electrons are elementary particles, they must be described quantum mechanically, and here are the feynman diagrams"

[image: brems]

Potentials do not enter because in quantum electrodynamics their effect is taken over by the virtual photon exchanges.

> There must be something missing in my understanding about the formation of bremsstrahlung. If all the electron's loss of kinetic energy is converted to electrical potential energy as it leaves the nucleus, where does the energy come from to create a radiated photon?

You are thinking classically about individual particles as an electron and a photon, that cannot be correct

The electron exchanges a virtual photon giving energy and momentum to the nucleus , and loses energy to a real photon.

Classically, if  a charged particle decelerates it emits radiation. The diagram above  is what happens at the quantum mecahnical correct level for electrons and photons and nuclei.